# jQuery alert not calling

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

## HTML

My button

```
<asp:Button ID="submitbtn" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="addchild()" CssClass="btn blue" />
```

## Javascript

and my javascript function

```
function addchild() {
        alert(1);
        $("#<%= submitbtn.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            alert(2);
            var firstnme = document.getElementById("<%=firstnametxt.ClientID%>");
            alert(firstnme);
            if (firstnme = "") {
                $("#<%=firstnametxt.ClientID%>").css("border", "1px solid red");
            }
        })
  }
```

and the second alert(2) is not calling and also jQuery click function is not calling please somebody help me to sort out the issue

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to use `$("#<%= submitbtn.ClientID %>").click(function () {})`
again?`addchild` function is firing once and you can use below code

```
function addchild() {
        alert(1);
        alert(2);
        var firstnme = document.getElementById("<%=firstnametxt.ClientID%>");
            alert(firstnme);
            if (firstnme = "") {
                $("#<%=firstnametxt.ClientID%>").css("border", "1px solid red");
            }
    }
```

Comment: yes ,  but my doubt is to why cant we fire a jquerry click event inside a js function

Comment: well,because $("#<%= submitbtn.ClientID %>").click(function () {}) never fires inside onclick event again

Answer (score 0):

try this jquery click function is not calling because you use asp.net button instead of html button

## Html:

```
 <input type="button" id="submitbtn"  value="Save" onclick="addchild()"/>
```

## jquery:

```
function addchild() {
    alert(1);
         $("#<%= submitbtn.ClientID %>").click(function () {
        alert(2);
        var firstnme = document.getElementById("  <%=firstnametxt.ClientID%>");
        alert(firstnme);
        if (firstnme = "") {
            $("#<%=firstnametxt.ClientID%>").css("border", "1px solid red");
        }
    });      
}
```